# Restrict search results to only documents user can see

Tags: search, theming

In my application, I have a content type called `resource`. In the resource content type, I have an `entity reference` that defines which roles should be able to view that resource.

When somebody is logged in as a certain role and does a search, he is able to view documents that don't belong to his role. How can I `hook` to the search results and remove the ones he should not be able to see?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this module will help you [Access by term](https://www.drupal.org/project/abt) and don't forget to enable Node access settings in search api settings.

Comment: This might help if I started using it in the beginning. But I have an existing application that I need to come up with a solution for given the structure that is currently in place on the website. Thanks.